# DOM methods and browser compatibility sites

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser

Is there a site anywhere that documents all standard JavaScript DOM methods, events and properties and when they were introduced into the various browsers? I've used W3Schools' [XML DOM Object Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_document.asp), but it's badly dated, it only tracks IE, Firefox, Opera and W3C, it's missing heaps of newer 'standard' methods, plus I'm certain I ran into something there that was wrong, but I can't remember what it was.

Half the time I write something now, I'm never certain that the methods my code relies on have the coverage I expect and I don't have the resources to test in every version of every browser out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really excellent resource is the ["Compatibility Master Table"](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html) at quirksmode.org.

Be sure to dive into the detail tables, linked in the left column.

.

> Half the time I write something now, I'm never certain that the methods my code relies on have the coverage I expect and I don't have the resources to test in every version of every browser out there.

This is why, increasingly, if I can't do it in jQuery, I don't do it or the boss/client pays mucho extra.  ;-)

Comment: Awesome. That's what I was after. You're right about using jQuery. But sometimes it's just too big and slow (e.g. for some mobile devices) to too overkill (e.g. if I need to inspect or manipulate just one element). I just don't like that uneasy feeling I get as soon as I start typing "getAttribute..." or "getElementsBy...". Creates a little knot in the pit of my stomach every time.